# Problem with import variable from text file and loop it

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to code a script with PowerShell and I'm stuck. Maybe you can send me a link or give a tip?

I write a command in PowerShell and I try to execute it on many servers with different domains:

```
$Username = 'domain\user'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
invoke-command -filepath \source_script.ps1 -computerName server07 -Credential $cred
```

i have a long list in serverlist.txt file something like this

1. city servername credential domain
2. city servername credential domain
3. city servername credential domain

and now im trying to do my script on many server in list, but not all server in list. For example, do this script only where city = berlin or london or moscow.

What should i do? How to load variable to $username $ password in loop.

I know how to do it with BATCH with powershell, but i must do it in PowerShell

Look at my batch file, how i do it before:

```
FOR /F %%a IN (\my_list.txt) DO TYPE \server_list.txt | find.exe "%%a" >> %source_path%\temporary_list.txt

::my_list.txt is the list all off my variables

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (\temporary_list.txt) do call :run_program %%A
:run_program
SET mycity=%1
SET myserver=%2
SET mycredentials=%3
SET mydomain=%4

psExec.exe -u %mydomain% %mycredentials% \\%myserver% blah blah blah, rest of script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this. First of all, import you server list, then iterate over it to decide which servers to work on...

```
#import your server list

$serverlist = Get-Content -path C:\path\to\serverlist.txt

#iterate over $serverlist, and only act on entries that match Berlin or London or Moscow, etc...

Foreach ($server in $serverlist | Where-Object {$_ -match ("Berlin|London|Moscow")}) {

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {

        #do work

    }

}
```

This method uses the foreach loop and a regex match alternator to look for Berlin, or London, or Moscow, in each line from your list.

**UPDATE**

To work with a large array of cities, it would be much more readable if you are working with a csv, with headers. Here is an example...

```
<#

import your server list as a csv

csv looks like this...

server,city,cred
server1,moscow,cred1
server2,london,cred1
server3,moscow,cred2
server4,berlin,cred1

#>

#import serverlist.csv...

$serverlist = Import-csv -path C:\scripts\lists\serverlist.csv

#import your city list...

$citylist = Get-Content -path C:\scripts\lists\citylist.txt

#iterate $serverlist and check if $citylist contains $_.City...

$serverlist | ForEach-Object {

    if ($citylist.Contains($_.City)) {

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -Credential $_.cred -ScriptBlock {

            #do work

        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you are working with .txt and not .csv, you can also match on the city.
 
If your serverlist.txt looks like this...

server city cred
server city cred
server city cred

...you can split each row of $serverlist and match on array index values. Powershell will index from 0, so to match on 'city', you would use index [1], etc...

```
$serverlist = Get-Content -path C:\scripts\lists\serverlist.txt

#import your city list...

$citylist = Get-Content -path C:\scripts\lists\citylist.txt

#iterate $serverlist
#split each row into a collection
#check if $citylist contains a match on index 1 (city 'column')...

$serverlist | ForEach-Object {

    $serverInfo = ($_).split(" ")

    if ($citylist.Contains($serverInfo[1])) {

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverInfo[0] -Credential $serverInfo[2] -ScriptBlock {

            #do work

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is good tip, but tell me is the way to change part "-match (berlin|London|Moscow|) to -match (something from text file). Maybe I need first to import text to variables??

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you want to match on a certain city, you can plug that into the alternator. You should be importing your server list (text file) first of all, as shown in my answer. You do that with Get-Content, since you said you had a .txt file with your server list in it.

Comment: Once you have your server list in $serverlist, you can match on anything you want, as long as it is a properly formatted collection of objects.

Comment: Yes in server list I have a hundred of servers where I have credential, servername and city where physically exist. But sometimes I must do some command on for example half servers in 50, 60 cities (from 140 cities). I have only list with cities. I can't image that I type all 50 cities in -match  (1city|2city|3city ... |60city|) time waste. I want to import my only city list to variable and use server list to get servername and credential.

Comment: Thank you! This is what i want to know! Thank you again!

Comment: Awesome. No problem!